# Expected Time on dice roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Wanted to just confirm whether I was doing the right thing:

Question: Jack repeatedly rolls a fair die. If it comes up 1, he instantly wins (and stops playing with no time elapsed). If it comes up $n$, where $n ∈ {2, 3, 4}$, he waits $n$ minutes and then rolls again. If it comes up $n$, where  $n ∈ {5, 6}$, he waits $n^{2}$ minutes and then rolls again. What is the expected elapsed time from when he starts rolling until he wins?

I've begun by conditioning on the outcome of the roll and the corresponding time elapsed. 
Hence, $E[X] = \frac{1}{6}(0)+\frac{1}{6}(2)+\frac{1}{6}(3)+\frac{1}{6}(4)+\frac{1}{6}(25)+\frac{1}{6}(36)=\frac{35}{3} \approx \:11.67$

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good start. Note that if he does not roll a $1$, he has to wait and then roll again. In other words, the process hasn't finished when Jack rolls a non-1 number. What you have calculated is exactly that.

Instead, what happens if he rolls a non-1? The process essentially starts over, except some number of minutes has been added to his time. We can reflect that in your equation by adding the original value $E[X]$ to each time in your sum:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{6}(0) + \frac{1}{6}(2 + E[X]) + \frac{1}{6}(3+E[X]) + \frac{1}{6}(4+E[X]) + \frac{1}{6}(25+E[X]) + \frac{1}{6}(36+E[X])$$.

After this, simply solve for $E[X]$ and you're done!

Note: The reason we don't add $E[X]$ to the first $0$ is because the process actually does finish in that case.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense, this is similar to the coal miner problem. Now I get it, thanks